# Find maximum and minimum days between several dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to find max. and min. days between several records in my table. For example, in the following table I would like to have max. and min. days due to DATE field for each ID.
I'm using MS-SQL 2013

I know that there is `dateiff` to finding days between two dates but now, I want to find maximum and minimum days between several dates.

```
ID DATE
10 2016/01/13
10 2016/01/10
10 2016/11/01
10 2015/12/28
11 2015/12/11
11 2016/02/01
11 2015/01/01
```

Now, how can I find max. and min. days between DATEs for each ID?

Can you please help me to have the query in SQL?

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: If you're looking at the days between two dates then there is no MAX or MIN, it's a static value. You're not very clear in your question, could you clarify the output that you're expecting. P.S. you might want to check your SQL version, 2013 isn't a valid version as far as I'm aware (went from 2012 to 2014).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've re-read your answer, are you looking for something like below;

Creating temp table and inserting data;

```
CREATE TABLE #DataTable (ID int, DATE DateTime)

INSERT INTO #DataTable (ID, DATE)
VALUES
(10, '2016-01-13')
,(10, '2016-01-10')
,(10, '2016-11-01')
,(10, '2015-12-11')
,(11, '2015-12-11')
,(11, '2016-02-01')
,(11, '2015-01-01')
```

Select statement to retrieve data;

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime; SET @StartDate = '2015-12-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime; SET @EndDate = '2016-12-01'

SELECT 
a.ID
,MIN(DATE) FirstDate
,MAX(DATE) LastDate
,DATEDIFF(day, MIN(DATE), MAX(DATE)) DayDiff
FROM #DataTable a
WHERE a.DATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY a.ID
```

You can remove the fields FirstDate and LastDate, this is just to show the dates that are being compared. You'll return a 0 value if there is only one date between your variable dates so you may have to account for this. Also probably a good idea to put something to check for a NULL.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is a bit ugly (using two subqueries) but should get you started:

```
CREATE TABLE #DataTable (id INT, [date] DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #DataTable (id, [date])
VALUES (10, '20160113')
    ,(10, '20160110')
    ,(10, '20161101')
    ,(10, '20151211')
    ,(11, '20151211')
    ,(11, '20160201')
    ,(11, '20150101')

SELECT
    id
    , MIN([days]) AS mindays
    , MAX([days]) AS maxdays
FROM (
    SELECT
        id
        , DATEDIFF(DAY, [date], (SELECT MIN([date]) FROM #DataTable AS D1 WHERE D1.id = #DataTable.id AND D1.[date] > #DataTable.[date])) AS [days]
    FROM #DataTable
) AS t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

Easiest way to understand is by starting at the middle query (which can be run on its own). It delivers for each row the id, and the number of days between the date in the row and the next higher one from the same id.

The outer query is then a simple MIN MAX GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
Select ID, Min(Date), Max(Date) From MyTable Group By ID
```